# saving last elements of a list into another grouped list

Tags: list-manipulation

If we have a list (data1) of 201*201 members as {a,b,c} (which a,b and c are numeric), how can we save them into another list (data2) containing just `c's` in the groups of 100 member as (I can use of `Last` but the problem is gathering them to 100 member groups)

```
data1={{a1,b1,c1},{a2,b2,c2},....,{a201,b201,c201},......,{a40401,b40401,c40401}}
data2={{c1,c2,c3,......c100},{c101,c102,....c200},{c201,...c300},....}
```

Comment: Use `Map[]`, `Last[]`, and `Partition[]`?

Comment: Out of curiosity, why not keep the c values in lists that are 201 elements long?  That way you keep the original structure and you don't have to throw any away (as in, throwing out data point number 40401)

Comment: this question is related to my previous question and I wanted to generate a new list which is similar to proposed by @george2079 (and you alerted me about its structure) and apply the process.

Comment: I could not add a note in previous question, your last answer about that was completely helpful, you wrote in a format understandable and translatable to me. Wonderful!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
data2 = Partition[data1[[All, 3]], 100]
```

References:

http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Part.html

http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Partition.html

Answer (score 2):

**Examples:**

```
(*arbitrary data*)
data = {{a1, b1, c1}, {a2, b2, c2}, {a3, b3, c3}};

(*Example No.1*)
data[[All, 3]][[1 ;; 3]]

(*Example No.2*)
Last @ # & /@ data
```

**Additional information:**

In *Example No.1* `data` is the dataset you operate on. `[[All,3]]` selects third item from each nested list and `[[1 ;; 3]]` selects the range of data you are interested in.

Likewise, in *Example No. 2* `data` is the dateset you operate on. Function `Last` is used to extract the last element from each sublist. For more information on syntax, please see **Reference** section below.

**Output:**

```
{c1, c2, c3}
```

**Reference:**

[Part](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Part.html)
[@ # /@ etc.](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/18393/what-are-the-most-common-pitfalls-awaiting-new-users/25616#25616)

Answer (score 1):

```
data2 = Table[data1[[100 i - 99 ;; 100 i, 3]], {i, 1, 201}]
```